# Display tag name and value in an xml file in java/unix

Tags: xml

I have a question, let's say I have an xml string such as the one below:

< request>SayHello< /request>< response>Wave< /response>

If I want the output to be:

Request: SayHello
Response: Wave

How would I proceed? I'm not looking for anything specific I just want to "format" the xml.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way with perl and regexes:

```
echo "<Request>SayHello</Request><Response>Wave</Response>" | perl -ne 'print "Request: $1 Response: $2\n" if /<Request>(.*?)<\/Request><Response>(.*?)<\/Response>/'
```

EDIT:

Ok and a bit more generic to catch and print any tags (put in file x.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

while (<STDIN>) {
    while ($_ =~ /<(.*?)>(.*?)<\/\1>/g) {
        print ($1 . ": " .  $2 . "\n");
    }   
}
```

Usage example would be:

```
echo "<Request>Hello</Request><Response>Goodbye</Response><Other>Foo</Other>"|./x.pl
```

EDIT2:

And then here's another way with java where you can pull out whatever you want based on an xpath expression:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Example {
    Example(String xml) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(xml);

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpresion expr = xpath.compile("/some/xml/path/text()");
        NodeList nl = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE_LIST);

        System.out.println("Node value: " + nl.items(0).getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Kevin, well yeah that worked, but what I want is to take the each tag name in the xml and display it alongside it's value regardless of the name itself. It's like formatting the xml in the following way : Request: Say hello regardless of the tag name, like a general functionality that would take each tag and put it that way

Comment: @GRIM: see my updated example. Note that it doesn't work for nested tags; not sure if that's something you're interested in.